# CQRS applicability when some commands need to block the UI

Tags: architecture, ui, cqrs

I am working on an app which I would dearly love to transition from a fairly traditional layered architecture to CQRS, for a number of reasons, not least fo which is that having a robust event log will make adding a couple of feature requests I can see barrelling towards me trivial to accomodate.

Now, I have a conceptual problem: of around 40 commands the user can initiate, there are three which the user *needs* to be sure have successfully completed before the UI lets them do anything else.  Everything else fits into the "submit a request, query for success later" model, except for these three commands.

How is this handled in CQRS-land? Do I separate the three blocking commands to effectively a third service, so I have Commands, Queries, and BlockingCommands? Do I have a two-stage event processor with an in-request blocking first stage which only gets used for the blocking commands?  Does the existence of these three commands mean that the whole idea of applying CQRS is invalid?  Should I just pretend they *aren't* blocking and poll for success in the UI?

I'm sure this must come up on other projects, how is it usually handled?

Answer (score 2):

No one ever said that all, or any for that matter, commands must be asynchrounous.  The core concept is to separate reads and writes.  When you use commands and events as the the transport mechanism, making them async is definitely easier.

Process these synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

it's easier to make an asynchronous operation seem synchronous, rather than the other way round.

you could use REST, and the UI, so that you provide a modal dialog, and provide a callback / poll for success. This would effectively allow you to have a mechanism for making it seem synchronous and modal.

It sounds though like you have a scenario that would benefit from a saga. Check out what Udi ( [www.udidahan.com](http://www.udidahan.com) ) and Greg Young ( skills matter ) have to say about this.

Comment: You have a point about the saga. Maybe I should rethink this.

Comment: thanks :). I would have said more about implementing a saga, but I wasn't clear on exactly the scenario you were describing, so thought it better that you 'go to the source' :) ( the last day of Greg's lectures pretty much cover what you need, so try looking for some of his newer talks/posts ) - Udi, has loads of resources about sagas.